# Mesh only moves in Blender units

Tags: objects, units

Im new to blender, so please explain the answer clearly. I don't know what I did, but now, my meshes only move in Blender Units - it's understandably annoying. The only way they move more or less freely is when I hold the control Key.

Using blender 2.72b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from snapping. You must've accidently turned it on. Click the magnet again to turn it off. You can find it at the bottom of the 3D viewport (the main window.)

[image]

When you *know* it's on, snapping is a helpful tool to move stuff exact distances without having to type it in.

Comment: Actually it's completely common. When I first started blender I got stuck cause I didn't know how to delete the cube. And I didn't know what the lamp was.

Comment: Been there 